# Crystal Reports 11 Dynamic Data Source Columns On Crystal Charts

Tags: crystal-reports

I've been searching for a solution for this issue for a couple of days now, so I would REALLY appreciate it if someone could help...

I am using SAP Crystal Reports 11, I would like to plot products prices over a specific period of time **(FROM & TO Dates)** using Crystal Line Chart.

The thing is the products number is dynamic, as each set of products belong to a package, so the package can contain 3, 5, 10 or any number of products depending on the chosen period of time **(The FROM & TO DATES)**. I want to display these prices on change of date.

So when using a crystal chart, it requests a fixed numbers of columns to display in the setup panel below the **"On Change Of"** Option.
I would like a way to determine the columns to display on the run-time or something.

If such an option isn't available, I would really appreciate any work around or any idea.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you saying that you have dynamic columns like product1, product2, product3, etc? Instead of a single product column and many rows?

Comment: Yes, I figured I would go this way. cause even if I had a single product column and many rows, how can this be different than multiple columns scenario? Because even if I did that, I still have to show product price values based on the change of dates, so even the dates are dynamic! 

But well, I I misunderstood you or you had other scenario in mind please let me know....
Thanks a lot for your reply :)